# 'Grid' identifier is not found when using NupenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I created a cpp file to hold some functions that I wanna call to convert from a Python code base. I did that successfully but an other function that takes input can't take the output from my function.

I don't know the start and end of this thing so I'm gonna post both of them.

In the executing file:

```
sprite.MoveTo(Vector3(Grid(1), Grid(1), 0));
```

In the converting file:

```
float LevelE::Grid(float GridPos) {
  ScreenPos = GridPos*160;
  return ScreenPos;
}
```

I figured all the things out that needs to get in the header file so no worries there and I also included the header files of course. Hope you can help. Also: the error message is:

> 'Grid' identifier is not found

Comment: Can you show us how to produce that error message on our own?

Comment: It's important to have a title that conveys the nature of the problem. Asking for help is the whole point of the site, so it's redundant to include that sort of thing. I've tried to trim this down to the basics so if I've messed anything up feel free to edit.

Comment: I can't show how you could produce this error message since this is all the code needed to do so I believe. that what I left out was the creation of the two variables in the header file and then the vector3 is a class that is basically aplicable to a 3 dimensional array I believe.

Comment: `Grid` is a method of the class `LevelE`. So you need an object of type `LevelE`: `LevelE l;` `l.Grid(1)`.

Comment: also thanks for the trimnent since this is one of the first times I used this site to ask for advice